# Flutter add multiple Sqlite tables, + table calendar

Tags: sqlite, flutter, calendar

1. I had a table named 'vocas', but I need to add one more table named 'repeat'. After searching, I found that I can add table with multiple `db.execute`, but how can I change the code `return db.execute`? I'm new to flutter, please help me to change it.

```
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_db != null) return _db;
    _db = openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'vocas.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        return db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE vocas(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, word TEXT, meaning TEXT, createTime TEXT)",
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
    return _db;
  }
```

2. The table 'repeat', which I want to add, would be like this to use function [table calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar).   Then, is it possible to make the table with Sqlite? In the [repeat] list, Is it also possible to add item in list with Sqlite? Thanks in advance.

```
repeat = {
           DateTime(2020, 8, 23) : ['repeat3'],            
           DateTime(2020, 8, 24) : ['repeat2', 'repeat4'], 
           DateTime(2020, 8, 25) : ['repeat1', 'repeat2', 'repeat3'], 
           DateTime(2020, 8, 26) : ['repeat3', 'repeat4'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you can just use `db.execute()` instead of `return db.execute()` to create more than one table.

```
Future<Database> database() async {
    return openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), "calendar.db"),
      onCreate: (db, version) async {
        await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE tasks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Activity TEXT)",
        );
        await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE progress (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Center REAL, Left REAL, Right REAL)",
        );
        await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE userInfo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Gender TEXT)",
        );
        return db;
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  }
```

Not sure what your second question is.